# How to pass Timestamp,date in request param in spring boot using Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want to pass timestamp as a request parameter in spring boot controller method

//entity class

```
@Entity
public class EventCalendar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;
    private String eventName;
    private String city;
    private String address;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createRecord;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startTime;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
    private Date endTime;
```

//controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/events")
public class controller{
    @GetMapping("/getevents8")
    public List<EventCalendar> getEvents8(@RequestParam int page,@RequestParam Date d1,@RequestParam Date d2 ){
        Sort sort=new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"createRecord");
        Pageable pageRequest =PageRequest.of(page, 3,sort);
        List<EventCalendar> events;
        
            events=eventRepository.findByCreateRecordBetween(d1, d2, pageRequest);
        
        return events;
        }
}
```

//timestamp example that I inserted using json

```
{

        "id":10,
        "eventName":"Kabbadi pro kidz",
        "city":"Noida",
        "address":"sector 63",
        "createRecord":"2020-03-31T15:45:01Z",
        "startTime":"2020-04-08T07:30:10Z",
        "endTime":"2020-04-09T10:15:18Z",
}
```

Now what I want to do is pass the time stamp in request Param

I am passing this request in postMan

http://localhost:8082/events/getevents8/?page=0&d1=2020-04-01T09:18:18Z&d2=2020-04-06T23:15:18Z

But getting this error:

```
eclipse
 Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'
Postman
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-31T10:11:34.196+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.util.Date] for value '2020-04-01T09:18:18Z'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
    "path": "/events/getevents8/"
}
```

I Do not know how to pass timestamp without the Json Object I want to know how to pass as a parameter in a request.

Comment: Where did you insert the Json in Postman?

Comment: I saved the timestamp in my entity when I passed the timestamp in Json object but I want to do it through request param

Comment: I think this could help you: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this format for your input

```
    2020-04-01T09:18:18Z -> @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

or use iso dateTime input like below

```
2020-04-01T09:18:18.000+00:00 -> @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
```

below code work with your input

```
@GetMapping("/getevents8")
    public List<EventCalendar> getEvents8(@RequestParam int page,
                                          @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") Date d1,
                                          @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") Date d2) {
        Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createRecord");
        Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, 3, sort);
        List<EventCalendar> events;

        events = eventRepository.findByCreateRecordBetween(d1, d2, pageRequest);

        return events;
    }
```